# Is the relationship between Ka and Kb the same for all acid base pairs?

Tags: acid-base, water

What is the relationship between $K_\mathrm{a}$ and $K_\mathrm{b}$ for acid/base reactions. I know for water $K_\mathrm{w}=K_\mathrm{a}\cdot K_\mathrm{b}$, where $K_\mathrm{w}$ is $10^{-14}$. Is this true for other acid/base pairs?

Comment: What do you mean by "other pairs"?

Comment: i meant other acids and their conjugate bases. E.g. CH3COO- and CH3COOH

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me put a statement to clarify the proper meanings of $K_\mathrm{a}$ and $K_\mathrm{b}$ for this case.
**The $K_\mathrm{a}$ is the acid dissociation constant of a weak acid, and the $K_\mathrm{b}$ is the dissociation constant of its conjugate base. Alternatively, we can also say, $K_\mathrm{b}$ is the base dissociation constant of a weak base, and $K_\mathrm{a}$ is the dissociation constant of its conjugate acid.**

We can deduce the same relationship, i.e. $K_\mathrm{a}\cdot K_\mathrm{b} = K_\mathrm{w}$, for these cases also. Without loss of generality, let the weak acid be $\ce{HA}$ and its conjugate base is $\ce{A^-}$ (you can also do the same [not identical] derivation considering base $\ce{B}$ and its conjugate acid $\ce{BH^+}$).

Considering acid dissociation, 
\begin{align}
\ce{HA &<=> H^+ + A^-}& 
K_\mathrm{a} &= \ce{\frac{[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}},
\end{align} 
and for the basic action of its conjugate base, consider,
\begin{align}
\ce{A^- + H2O &<=> HA + OH^-}&
K_\mathrm{b} &= \ce{\frac{[HA][OH^-]}{[A^-]}}.
\end{align} 
Multiplying both the equations, we will have, 
$$
K_\mathrm{a}\cdot K_\mathrm{b} 
= \ce{\frac{[A^-][H^+]}{[HA]}}\cdot \ce{\frac{[HA][OH^-]}{[A^-]}} 
= \ce{[H^+][OH^-]} = K_\mathrm{w}$$ 
So, it is proved that for any acid/conjugate base pair (or, base/conjugate acid pair) the identical relation, $K_\mathrm{a}\cdot K_\mathrm{b} = K_\mathrm{w}$ holds.

Comment: I have corrected the use of MathJax in your post. Please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945) for more information.

Comment: @Soumik Das,the last step you did,is multiplying ka and kb for different reaction,in that case,[H+] is the concentration of ion at equillibrium of reaction 1 while,[OH-] Is concentration of [OH-] at equillibrium of second reaction,how do we know that their product must equal kw,because these are two different reactions,the result [h+][oh-]=kw is proved if both concentrations are from same aqueous solution